# Running Haddock on its own

Tags: haskell, haddock

I would like to start using Haddock; the primary reason is not that I do (or anyone else does) need nice HTML documentation for what I'm writing right now, but that it will teach me a standardized way commenting Haskell modules.
For this reason, I'd like to get my hands dirty with it, but I've run into a pretty basic problem.

Source:

```hs
module Main where
-- |This is the main function.
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

Haddock invocation:

```
> haddock -h test.hs 
Haddock coverage:
  50% (  1 /  2) in 'Main'
Warning: Main: could not find link destinations for:
    GHC.Types.IO
```

It looks like Haddock doesn't know where to look for the standard libraries, but that's just a wild guess. The docs say something about a "-B" parameter, but are not really explaining much about it.

I've searched for the problem online, and it was basically answered with "use a Cabal package and it'll do everything for you". However, I would much rather not deal with Cabal right now, but learn Haddock on its own (Cabal can wait). Is there a nice and easy(ish) solution to the problem?

Comment: Just to put a data point out there: I have written a lot of documentation and never once invoked `haddock` by hand.

Comment: Correct, haddock doesn't know where to find the docs for the installed libraries by itself, you have to tell it. I'm not an expert, but the `--read-interface=FILE` option tells haddock where to find the docs. However, letting `cabal` do the job is much simpler.

Comment: Cabal is meant to make your life easier. Why wait?

Comment: I'd also suggest you to use [cabal](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/). It makes a lot of things easier (not just haddock) and it's easy to set up.

Comment: FWIW, I see warnings like this every single time I ask Cabal to build Haddock for anything. I assumed it was just something that always happens... (Or maybe just on Windows.)

Comment: On the `-B` option - I have been trying to figure out how to call Haddock. Like OP, I figured I'd need the `-B` option. I found the `lib` folder for the Haskell platform (which contains the `settings` file that `-B` seems to look for). Specifying that correctly doesn't cause new errors, but doesn't get rid of the `link destinations` error either. So I can confirm that at least it's not as simple as specifying that one option, and I suspect Haddock already knows that path and the errors are about something else. Possible `--read-interface` is needed for each library used.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to echo the wisdom of the comments to your question and say, just use Cabal. It's not an extra thing to learn, it's something to learn *instead* precisely because it takes care of all these tedious details for you. You'll probably need to know about it anyway since everyone else uses it, so you might as well get the benefit of that knowledge.

For completeness, I ran `cabal haddock -v` on one of my projects, and this is the invocation of `haddock` that it used:

> `/usr/local/bin/haddock --prologue=dist/doc/html/notcpp/haddock-prolog1566.txt --dump-interface=dist/doc/html/notcpp/notcpp.haddock --optghc=-package-name --optghc=notcpp-0.2.0.2 --hide=NotCPP.Utils --verbosity=1 --html --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.1,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/array-0.4.0.1/array.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.0/base.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/containers-0.5.0.0/containers.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/deepseq-1.3.0.1,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/deepseq-1.3.0.1/deepseq.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/ghc-prim-0.3.0.0/ghc-prim.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/integer-gmp-0.5.0.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/integer-gmp-0.5.0.0/integer-gmp.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/pretty-1.1.1.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/pretty-1.1.1.0/pretty.haddock --read-interface=/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/template-haskell-2.8.0.0,/usr/local/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/template-haskell-2.8.0.0/template-haskell.haddock --odir=dist/doc/html/notcpp/ --title=notcpp-0.2.0.2: Avoiding the C preprocessor via cunning use of Template Haskell --optghc=-fbuilding-cabal-package --optghc=-O --optghc=-odir --optghc=dist/build/tmp-1566 --optghc=-hidir --optghc=dist/build/tmp-1566 --optghc=-stubdir --optghc=dist/build/tmp-1566 --optghc=-i --optghc=-idist/build --optghc=-i. --optghc=-idist/build/autogen --optghc=-Idist/build/autogen --optghc=-Idist/build --optghc=-optP-include --optghc=-optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h --optghc=-hide-all-packages --optghc=-package-id --optghc=base-4.6.0.0-eac4fa0d0988628e5bd960fef8805b26 --optghc=-package-id --optghc=template-haskell-2.8.0.0-102a52a4fda28374255d0a3a8e99f26c --optghc=-XHaskell98 --optghc=-XTemplateHaskell --optghc=-W -B/usr/local/lib/ghc-7.6.1 dist/build/tmp-1566/NotCPP/ScopeLookup.hs dist/build/tmp-1566/NotCPP/LookupValueName.hs dist/build/tmp-1566/NotCPP/OrphanEvasion.hs dist/build/tmp-1566/NotCPP/Utils.hs`

Now, I'm sure much of that is optional, but I'm not about to spend the time working out which bits are and which aren't.